# Returning boolean from SQL function

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I'm trying to write a PL/pgSQL function in postgres that returns a boolean expression.  Currently the code looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_visible_to(role integer, from_role integer)
  RETURNS boolean
  LANGUAGE SQL STABLE STRICT AS $$
    RETURN $1 = $2 OR first_predicate($1, $2) OR second_predicate($2, $1);
 $$;
```

The functions first_predicate and second_predicate exist and return booleans, but I'm not getting much help looking at them because they are defined with something like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) > 0 FROM ... WHERE ...
```

I am getting the following syntax error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "RETURN"
LINE 4:     RETURN $1 = $2 first_predicate($1, $2) OR second_predicate(...
            ^
```

So obviously I'm misunderstanding something rather fundamental here.  I'm sort of new to the whole PL/pgSQL thing, so links to a good tutorial or two would also be appreciated.

The project I'm working on uses postgres exclusively, and already contains a lot of postgres specific code, so solutions don't have to be portable to other databases.

**Edit:**
Fixed it myself with

```
CREATE FUNCTION is_visible_to (role integer, from_role integer)
  RETURNS BOOLEAN AS '
    DECLARE
        role ALIAS FOR $1;
        from_role ALIAS FOR $2;
    BEGIN
      RETURN (role = from_role) OR
             first_predicate(from_role, role) OR
             second_predicate(from_role, role)
    END;
' LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Would still appreciate an answer that explains why the later works and the former (even with the language changed to `plpgsql` as suggested by @a_horse_with_no_name) does not, or provides some useful tutorials.

Comment: Your function is defined as `language sql`. There is no `return` statement in sql, only in PL/pgSQL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I changed `language sql` to `langauge plpgsql`, same error.

Comment: Works with `language sql`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7cf4a/1 and `plpgsql`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/90f62/1 Btw: the language name is an identifier, so no single quotes please `plpgsql` or `sql` but not `'plpgsql'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry, I was doing something else stupid.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### SQL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_visible_to(role integer, from_role integer)
  RETURNS boolean AS
$func$
   SELECT $1 = $2 OR first_predicate($1, $2) OR second_predicate($2, $1);
$func$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE STRICT;
```

With `SELECT`. There is no `RETURN` in plain SQL. [Details in the manual here.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc-sql.html)

#### PL/pgSQL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_visible_to(role integer, from_role integer)
  RETURNS boolean AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN $1 = $2 OR first_predicate($1, $2) OR second_predicate($2, $1);
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE STRICT;
```

`BEGIN` and `END` are required for PL/pgSQL. [Details in the manual here.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql.html)

Don't use the outdated (and redundant here) `ALIAS FOR` syntax. [It's discouraged in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-ALIAS) You can reference parameter names directly (in SQL functions, too, since pg 9.2).

Comment: Is there a reason you refer to the arguments as `$1` and `$2`, instead of `role` and `from_role` in the function body?

Comment: @Jay: Either is valid in Postgres 9.2+ functions. The OP did not disclose his version, so positional references were the safe bet. There is a hint at the end of my answer. More: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27116711/939860