# Syntax error at or near ","

Tags: postgresql, function, if-statement, plpgsql

I have problems with this function and couldn't figure out how to fix it.

```
Create Function Quy(sdate timestamp)
returns integer as $$
declare
        numbmonth integer;
        quy integer;
Begin
    numbmonth := Date_part('month',sdate);
    If numbmonth < 4 then
        quy := 1;
    else if numbmonth < 7 then
        quy := 2;
    else if numbmonth < 10 then
        quy := 3;
    else quy := 4;
    return quy;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This happens when I try to run the code:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
> LINE 16: END;
> ```

I really don't understand what is wrong with this.

Comment: Tried removing the ; after END?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple syntax errors. The function would work like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION quy(sdate timestamp)
  RETURNS integer AS
$func$
DECLARE
   numbmonth integer := date_part('month', sdate);
   quy integer;
BEGIN
   IF numbmonth < 4 THEN
      quy := 1;
   ELSIF numbmonth < 7 THEN
      quy := 2;
   ELSIF numbmonth < 10 THEN
      quy := 3;
   ELSE
      quy := 4;
   END IF;
   RETURN quy;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

[Consult the manual for the basic syntax of `IF`.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS)

But that's much ado about nothing. To get the *quarter of the year* use the field specifier `QUARTER` with [`date_part()` or `EXTRACT()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) in a simple expression:

```
EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM $timestamp)
```

`EXTRACT` is the standard SQL equivalent of `date_part()`.
Either returns `double precision`, so cast to `integer` if you need that (`::int`).

If you still need a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION quy(sdate timestamp)
  RETURNS int LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
'SELECT EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM $1)::int';
```

`$1` is the reference to the 1st function parameter. Equivalent to `sdate` in the example. `$`-notation works in any version of Postgres, while named parameter references in SQL functions were only introduced with Postgres 9.2. See:

- [PLPGSQL Function to Calculate Bearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27110599/plpgsql-function-to-calculate-bearing/27116711#27116711)

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=3a12a00bd9fe64549fb9b9d195d21c95)*

Comment: the first function got a syntax error in the last row, the second has a result return 5, and can u explain the $1 in datep_part for me? I'm newbie in SQL

Comment: @Mr.X: Sorry, the expression in the simple function had a bug. I fixed it. But syntax error in the first? I don't think so. See demo: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=8d39a48305ac72031b6f4c09883414b9 You should *always* provide your version of Postgres with any related question.

Comment: @Mr.X: On second thought, there is a simpler solution, yet. Consider the update.

Comment: Thank you, I haven't learnt much about Extract but I'll use it when I do

Comment: @Mr.X: Don't get me wrong, `date_part('quarter', $1)` works as well. Just slipping in the standard SQL syntax.